# jquery - how to do recursive function to reset/maintain time delay on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, sprite

Im trying to make an animation using library from http://spritely.net/. Im triggering it by using .onscroll() - but Im struggling to stop scroll event firing too often and it speeds up the animation too much because it gets called to start many times per second by .onscroll()

Im able to stop scroll event firing too often the first time I scroll by setting a variable according to current time

I am unable to keep the delay going for the subsequent scroll events, the variable is less and less effective after each scroll

How can I keep it so that scroll only ever triggers the animation to start once, per scroll event so that it stays a constant pace no matter how many times I start and stop the animation by starting and stopping scrolling ?
Heres the demo
http://jsfiddle.net/fGmbe/109/

heres the code

```
var t, l = (new Date()).getTime(), scrolling = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){
var now = (new Date()).getTime();

if(now - l > 800 && !scrolling ){
     $('#bird').sprite({fps:6, no_of_frames: 16, rewind: true   });
    l = now;

}

clearTimeout(t);
t = setTimeout(function(){
    if (!scrolling)
       $('#bird').spStop()
}, 300);
 });


  var a, b = (new Date()).getTime(), scrolling = false;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  var nw = (new Date()).getTime();
  if(nw - b > 800 && !scrolling ){
  $('#bird').spStart({fps:8, no_of_frames: 16, rewind: true })
  l = nw;
    }
   });

 var c, d = (new Date()).getTime(), scrolling = false;
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  var nx = (new Date()).getTime();
  if(nx - d > 800 && !scrolling ){
  $('#bird').spStart({fps:8, no_of_frames: 16, rewind: true })
  l = nx;
    }
   });
```

Comment: Before you start a new animation stop the previous one. I'm not sure what animation library you're using, check the documentation if it has a `stop` function.

Comment: there is a stop in there

Comment: Well then, there are not enough stops in there ;)

Comment: maybe you are right - thought it was more to do with stopping .scroll triggers, given that the animation does only increase speed after stopping and starting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fire a handler just once for an event, `debounce` it!

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

If the event fires again within a set period, the handler is delayed.

Edit:

Quick example of how to achieve the functionality you're after. Note the second argument I'm passing to `$.debounce`, which is a boolean defining whether the event handler should run at the start or at the end of the event.

http://jsfiddle.net/nubwG/

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll($.debounce(500, true, startSomething));
    $(window).scroll($.debounce(500, false, stopSomething));

    function startSomething(){
        // start animating here
    }

    function stopSomething(){
        // stop animating here
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the advice- i think its helped. Not sure http://jsfiddle.net/fGmbe/116/ maybe im not using it right

Comment: @jojojohn You are using it incorrectly. You should wrap your functionality in a function, and pass the function name to $.debounce. Here is a very basic example. http://jsfiddle.net/Svcd8/ You'll see that it waits half a second for you to stop scrolling before it runs the alert function.

Comment: @jojojohn Here is a further example which demonstrates starting some functionality when the user starts scrolling, and stopping it when they stop, simples. :) http://jsfiddle.net/nubwG/

Comment: Thanks for this. I think Im getting there but it still seems to increase after every scroll -after 10 scrolls it is very fast- is there a way to multiply the delay after each scroll? See here to see what I mean .http://jsfiddle.net/atyM6/1/

Comment: I'm not familiar with spritely, but I managed to get it working by creating the sprite on scroll, and destroying it when you stop scrolling. You should be able to use the start and stop methods though. Here is a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/Nn7RV/

Comment: 'Destroy!!!' Thanks so much for this @Tom. You have really helped me. I don't know if I ever would have found that function on my own. Cheers